# get all text from all elements, replace certain predetermined words, javascript only

Tags: javascript, search, text, replace, find

I am trying to retrieve all the text on a document or webpage when a User loads the page,
I am trying to search all the text for certain words, defined by a [name value] array,
I am trying to replace each instance of the searched for words with the corresponding value.

example

I am using a chrome extension to inject My js upon page load...

```
<document>
       <head>web page</head>
          <body>
             <p>paragraph of text. stack overflow is wonderful</p>
             <p>another paragraph of text. stack overflow is great</p>
             <p>third paragraph with nested list
                 <ol>
                    <li>stack overflow yay</li>
                    <li>stack overflow wow</li>
                 </ol>
                 <img alt"stack is fun"></img>
             </p>
           </body>
```

the word stack appears many times in many context and tags.
I would like search the entire document using the name value pair [stack : snack, wonderful : excellent],
and then replace the original word with the new value.
the page should refresh with the new words in place of the old, so
every instance of stack should now say snack,
every instance of wonderful should now say excellent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply `replace` the `body` `innerHTML` with a `global flag` in `regex` (`g`).

In the snippet i created an `array` of `objects` with a `name` and `value` where `name` is going to be the target and the `value` is the replacement of `name`. I loop through `array` and do a `regex` with a `global flag` on `document.body.innerHTML` to replace all matching ocurrencies.

Just like so.

```js
const words = [
  {
    "targetValues": ["stack", "sack", "stck"],
    "value": "snack"
  },
  {
    "targetValues": ["wonderful"],
    "value": "amazing"
  }
];

words.forEach(word => {
    word.targetValues.forEach(target => {
    console.log(target);
    let reg = new RegExp(target, "gi");
    document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(reg, word.value);
  })
})
```

```html
<p>paragraph of text. sTacK overflow is wonderFul</p>
<p>another paragraph of text. stack overflow is great</p>
<p>third paragraph with nested list
  <ol>
    <li>stack overflow yay</li>
    <li>stack overflow wow</li>
  </ol>
  <img alt="stack is fun" />
  sack
</p>
<p>sack misspelled</p>
<p>stck misspelled again</p>
<p>sTcK misspelled again and with some capital characters</p>
```

More information about `RegExp` can be found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

**EDIT:**

If you want instead of passing one value in `name` you can pass an `array` of values, so you had to loop through the `name`s `array` and get each value to be replaced with the `value`;
Also, Yes you can do it by specifying the `case insensitive flag` using regex (`i`).

Take a look at the snippet code, i have made an update.

Also for further information i would advise you to see this link: https://javascript.info/regexp-introduction (this also explains `regex flag`s)

Comment: this is exactly what I was trying to do, thanks so much! and to elaborate, is there a way I can assign multiple words in the "name" , such as "name"; "stack", "shack", "smack", and have any of those words equal the same value. My actual example is for documents that say GOD, I am replacing all the lowercase or mispelled instances with the uppercase or correct spelling. ie god, God, or gOd would then be replaced with GOD from the value in the array ?

Comment: I've made an update to the post and edit the code snipped.